# php/forms two forms using upload.php which uploads a certain file name. how to parse the forms?

Tags: php, html

Actually I could duplicate my upload.php, change the file names and call it a day. But how can you do what I'm trying to do with only one upload.php?

My upload script changes the file name to msg1.txt.... I have two forms, how can I call the same upload.php with each for and get mes1.txt, and if form two mes2.txt?
this is all under a local domain so security is not an issue...
here is my form...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

any help in this area is appreciated. Thank you..

here is my upload.php

```
<?php

$destination_path = $_REQUEST["destination"] . "upload/"; 
$target_path = "" . $destination_path;
$target_path = $target_path . 'msg1.txt'; 
$_POST['dest_name'];
echo "User=" .          $_ENV[USER] . "<br />";
echo "Source=" .        $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] . "<br />"; 
echo "Destination=" .   $destination_path . "<br />"; 
echo "Target path=" .   $target_path . "<br />"; 
echo "Size=" .          $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] . "<br />"; 
//echo "Tmp name=" .    $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] . "<br />"; 


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a hidden input in both forms, called for example msg_type but with different values in each one,

**Your first form**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="msg_type" value="1" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**Your second form**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="msg_type" value="2" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**Then in your script**

```
$message_type = $_POST['msg_type'];

if ($message_type == 1) {
    $target_path = $target_path . 'msg1.txt';
}
else if ($message_type == 2) {
    $target_path = $target_path . 'msg2.txt';
}
else {
    $target_path = $target_path . 'unknown_form.txt';
}
```

You get from $_POST the value of the hidden field you had set on the form and then you proceed as you need to